# One fragment with two types of display

Tags: android

I need a fragment that sometimes shows in a container and sometimes shows as a dialog.

this sample code maybe help

```
MyFragment frag=new MyFragment();

//sometimes   
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, frag, tag);

//sometimes 
frag.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```

Comment: Where is the question, and what have you used, for now?

Comment: Please supply some code, we've no idea where to start with this!

Comment: Could you add some more details, or show us what you have now ? Have you looked at simply creating a custom Dialog with a Fragment in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fragment which extends DialogFragment as either embedded view or dialog. Please refer to this part of guide in documentation for detailed explanation. I have used this approach and it works perfectly.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#DialogOrEmbed

Comment: Tanks . This line code: 'frag.setShowsDialog(false);' helped.